# Vector template class create() function not defined

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following excerpt of a template class for a vector, from Koenig's accelerated c++, chapter 11.2:

```
template <class T> class Vec {
    public:
        typedef T* iterator;
        typedef const T* const_iterator;
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        Vec() { create(); }
        explicit Vec(size_type n, const T& val = T()) { create(n, val); }
       // new operations: size and index
       size_type size() const { return limit - data; }
       T& operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; }
       const T& operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; }
    private:
       iterator data;
       iterator limit;
};
```

This code should be the implementation of a vector class.

My doubt is precisely where should the funtion create() be defined? The book explains this function as follows:

> The default constructor, which is the one that takes no arguments, needs to indicate that the Vec is empty (i.e., that it has no elements). It does so by calling a member called create, that we'll have to write. When we return from create, we intend for both data and limit to be set to zero.

But it is never defined?

I've tried to compile the code, but the following error is returned:

main.cpp: In constructor ‘Vec::Vec()’:
main.cpp:9:9: error: there are no arguments to ‘create’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘create’ must be available [-fpermissive]

Comment: There is explicitly written "It does so by calling a member called create, that we'll have to write" So you need to define the member function in the class.

Comment: Indeed it will not compile as the create() method is not defined. Are you sure you've followed exactly what the book says ? may be the definition of this method was done in a previous chapter .... otherwise  you should contact the editor of the book

Comment: "that we'll have to write". That is, it is not written yet. It's either defined later in the book, or left as an exercise for you.

Comment: One thing to add is that this code uses two versions of `create`, one with no arguments and one with two. I find it a bit strange, but it seems either that you are supposed to write these by yourself, or that they are going to be added latter in the chapter.

Comment: The other odd thing is that although the class contains two iterators it's not clear what container those two iterators are supposed to refer to. Very strange, I can only guess that you are supposed to read on where the mystery will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is never defined?

If/when you read later part of the book, you'll find the implementations for `create` member functions as quoted below from the book:

> **We shall begin by looking at the various create functions**, which are responsible for allocating
> memory, initializing elements in that memory, and setting the pointers appropriately. In each
> case, we initialize whatever memory is allocated and so, after running create, the pointers
> limit and avail are always equal: The last constructed element is the same as the last
> allocated element. You should verify for yourself that the class invariant is true after we have
> executed any of the following functions:
>
> ```
> template <class T> void Vec<T>::create()
> {
>     data = avail = limit = 0;
> }
> template <class T> void Vec<T>::create(size_type n, const T& val)
> {
>     data = alloc.allocate(n);
>     limit = avail = data + n;
>     uninitialized_fill(data, limit, val);
> }
> template <class T>
> void Vec<T>::create(const_iterator i, const_iterator j)
> {
>     data = alloc.allocate(j - i);
>     limit = avail = uninitialized_copy(i, j, data);
> }
> ```
>
> The **version of** `create` **that takes no arguments creates an empty Vec, so its job is to ensure
> that the pointers start out with zero values.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm having difficulty understanding how this function can be implemented, because

if I write it before the template <class T> class Vec, it is extending a class that does not exist yet (expressed by the compilation error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token);

if I write it after, I have the same problem as before.

Comment: @ArthurFagundes For further/follow up questions feel free to ask a separate question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what exact error you're getting. In the comments section it is hard to understand what you mean by "before" and "after" without looking at any code. *You can ask a separate question and close this one* if it solved your current problem. One question per post is the preferred rule. You're welcome.

Comment: Ok I've closed this question because it was answered, thank you, but the follow up would not require a new question I think: I really only copied this definition of create() either before or after the Vec class code on my original question, and got the two cases that I've mentioned (copied before, copied after)

Comment: @ArthurFagundes Ok then I would recommend copy/pasting your solution at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) and then sharing that link here in the comments so that i can see what is wrong with it.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/KnTYch9cc

Comment: @ArthurFagundes See this [working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bT15e6sE8) where I've fixed/removed the errors by adding declarations for the `create` member functions inside the class and also moving the definitions of those after the class(not before it).